# "Remote host identification has changed" LOOP

Tags: linux, ssh, server, ssh-keygen

I met this error:

```
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@    WARNING: REMOTE HOST IDENTIFICATION HAS CHANGED!     @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
IT IS POSSIBLE THAT SOMEONE IS DOING SOMETHING NASTY!
Someone could be eavesdropping on you right now (man-in-the-middle attack)!
It is also possible that a host key has just been changed.
The fingerprint for the RSA key sent by the remote host is
21:0e:54:f2:0c:d8:bc:a1:1c:72:e0:3b:e9:ae:f9:82.
Please contact your system administrator.
Add correct host key in /nfs/home/kkochetov/.ssh/known_hosts to get rid of this message.
Offending ECDSA key in /nfs/home/kkochetov/.ssh/known_hosts:1
  remove with: ssh-keygen -f "/nfs/home/kkochetov/.ssh/known_hosts" -R 192.168.1.71
RSA host key for 192.168.1.71 has changed and you have requested strict checking.
Host key verification failed.
```

After `ssh-keygen -R 192.168.1.71`, the problem was solved, but only on ~10 minutes. Then server dropped me and after the next connection try I receive the same error again. Then I type `ssh-keygen -R 192.168.1.71` again, but after this moment my password no longer fits. 
Whats the problem?
If I try to do the same pipeline on another machine it will be the same. (First try is OK, but after 10 min and second try the same problem)

Can anybody help me?

Comment: I would ask your system administrator...

Comment: just do what it says. add correct host key into nfs/home/....

Comment: I'm administrator:)